# Retrieve textbox values in code behind file asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Hi I have a crontrol on the page:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="q" runat="server" autocomplete="off" />
```

which I'm trying to access the value of from the code behind file.

I've tried:

```
TextBox searchTerm = FindControl("q") as TextBox;
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If it is an `ASP.NET TextBox server control` which is inside your form, you can  simply use the `Text` property

```
string searchKey=q.Text;
```

You can access any elements inside your CodeBehind if it has an `ID` property with a value and `Runat` Property value set to `"Server"`

**Ex** : You can write some markup like this in your `.ASPX` page

```
<div id="someInfoDiv" runat="server"> Tim's point is valid</div>
```

and in codebehind

```
 someInfoDiv.InnerHtml = "So i am adding that";
```

Comment: As a note, you can access any element this way so long as it has an id assigned and the runat attribute set to "server", even if it is not an ASP.Net control.

Comment: @TimCopenhaver: Agreed. I willmention that in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to search it this way `TextBox searchTerm = FindControl("q") as TextBox;`
because it is a server control you will able to get the text by its id

this way `string query = q.Text;`